# Jquery: Autofill multiple input fields with value based on dropdown selection

Tags: jquery

I would like to fill multiple input fields with a value that I select from a dropdown. Below is the code I have

Selection:

```
<div class="col-4">
    <select class="custom-select" id="slbrand">
       <option selected>Please Select</option>
       <option data-brand="Toyota" value="1">Toyota</option>
       <option data-brand="Nissan" value="2">Nissan</option>
       <option data-brand="Mazda" value="3">Mazda</option>
    </select>
```

HTML fields (there are 68 of them):

```
<table id="producttable" class="display table table-bordered mt-2" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Metrics</th>
                <th>Value</th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<tr>
   <td class="labelfont">Wheels</td>
   <td><input id="row-1-value" name="row-67-value" type="text"></td>
</tr>
.
.
.
<tr>
  <td class="labelfont">Steering</td>
  <td><input id="row-68-value" name="row-68-value" type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

JQUERY:

```
//I can fill for one field, but how can I change it to fill all the row values
$('#slbrand').change( function() {
    //Autofill input ward fields with option value
    $("[input]").each(function () {
        $('#row-1-value').val($(this).attr('data-brand'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to use loop, just do that

```
$('input[id^=row-]').val("what you want");
```

**$('input[id^=row-]')** means  select all tags `input` with `id` beginning by `row-`

fyi in the loop

```
$("[input]").each(function () {
    $('#row-1-value').val($(this).attr('data-brand'));
});
```

`$(this)` dont reference to your value changed, but to selector `[input]`